# Piping curl followed by an echo some times truncates the output when using tail

Tags: bash, curl, echo

Given the following 2 lines in a bash script,

```
LOCATION=$(curl -i -H "Windmill-Name: $APPLICATION_NAME" -H "Windmill-Identifier: $CFBundleIdentifier" -F "ipa=@$IPA" -F "plist=@$PLIST" $WINDMILL_BASE_URL/windmill/rest/windmill/$USER | grep ^Location | awk '{print $2}')
echo "[windmill] Use $LOCATION for accessing '$APPLICATION_NAME'"
```

In some cases, the **echo** string appears like below.

> for accessing 'MultiPartIOSDemo'***[a truncated $LOCATION]***

The behaviour is not consistent but when it reproduces, the malformed output is consistent (i.e. a truncated $LOCATION at some range).

It looks like echo outputs the string to the buffer but the piping of curl isn't yet done and ends up writing its output on top.

Can't quite tell.

**Update**

Tried all of your suggestions, but the same problem occurs.

Have now dropped grep and the script looks like so

```
LOCATION=$(curl -i -H "Windmill-Name: $APPLICATION_NAME" -H "Windmill-Identifier: $CFBundleIdentifier" -F "ipa=@$IPA" -F "plist=@$PLIST" "$WINDMILL_BASE_URL/windmill/rest/windmill/$USER" | awk -W '/^Location/ {print $2}')
echo "[windmill] Use $LOCATION for accessing '$APPLICATION_NAME'"
```

Here are some more details.

The script that includes the above lines is wrapped in a

```
(
(
# bash script
) 2>&1 | tee $HOME/.windmill/$PROJECT_NAME.log

) 2>&1 | tee $HOME/.windmill/windmill.log
```

Hence the output of the **echo** is on both logs.

**Just noticed that the above behaviour occurs while tailing**, e.g.

```
tail -fn 20 ~/.windmill/windmill.log
```

However if I do a

```
more ~/.windmill/windmill.log
```

I can see that the echo message appears correctly. Notice the newline character "^M". Wondering if it has anything to do with the way tail parses the log.

> [windmill] Use ***[correct $LOCATION]*** **^M** for accessing 'MultiPartIOSDemo'

**Clarified Question**
Guess after all the above, there are really 2 questions.

1. Under what circumstances does the ^M appear in the log?
2. Why is tail parsing the log wrong, i.e. parsing ^M in such a way that it first outputs the "for accessing 'MultiPartIOSDemo'" then the "Use $LOCATION" on top.

Comment: Are you using Cygwin? You can change a ^m to a new line using "tr '\015' '\012' "

Comment: Not using Cygwin. That's on OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 0):

I would (1) change

```
$WINDMILL_BASE_URL/windmill/rest/windmill/$USER
```

to

```
"$WINDMILL_BASE_URL/windmill/rest/windmill/$USER"
```

(2) use tee to debug
and (3) use awk to match "^location" instead of grep

```
LOCATION=$(curl -i -H "Windmill-Name: $APPLICATION_NAME" -H "Windmill-Identifier: $CFBundleIdentifier" -F "ipa=@$IPA" -F "plist=@$PLIST" "$WINDMILL_BASE_URL/windmill/rest/windmill/$USER" | tee /tmp/debug.$$ | awk ' /^Location/ {print $2}')
echo "[windmill] Use $LOCATION for accessing '$APPLICATION_NAME'"
```

Comment: I see your changes. The ^M might be an issue. I still suggest you put the tee between the curl and awk - so you can see the input to awk. By using

Comment: I still suggest you put the tee between the curl and awk - so you can see the input to awk. By using "... | tee /tmp/trace.\
$$ | awk ..." you can capture each version and store it in a unique file ($$ expands to the process ID) so you capture the results of each and every case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps curl is returing an error. You can check the results and only parse it if no error occured

```
# Create a trace file
tfile=/tmp/trace.$$

# uncomment this line if you want to delete the trace file at the end of the script
#trap "/bin/rm $tfile" 0 1 15

curl -i -H "Windmill-Name: $APPLICATION_NAME" -H "Windmill-Identifier: $CFBundleIdentifier" -F "ipa=@$IPA" -F "plist=@$PLIST" "$WINDMILL_BASE_URL/windmill/rest/windmill/$USER" >$tfile
status=$?
if [ $status -eg 0 ]
then
    echo curl was successful
    LOCATION=$(awk '/^Location/ {print $2}' <$tfile)
    echo "[windmill] Use $LOCATION for accessing '$APPLICATION_NAME'"
else
    echo curl exited with status $status
fi
```